# Good resource for studying Database High Availability techniques

Tags: database

Can anybody suggest some good resource/book on Database high availability techniques?
Moreover, High-availability of system software like Intrusion Prevention system or Web servers. 
I am considering high-availability is global term which covers clustring, cloud computing, replication, replica management, distributed synchronization for cluster.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the book "High Performance MySQL". There are a lot of really good bits of information  regarding data partitioning, federation, indexing strategies, etc that can be applied to DB and storage systems other than MySQL.